# Ruby on Rails undefined method `referrals_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting the following error when trying to do a form write data on my database (sqlite3)

`` undefined method `referrals_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000008cc8> ``

My `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
...
  post "afiliados", to: "afiliados#create"
...
end
```

My `afiliados_controller.rb`

```
class AfiliadosController < ApplicationController
...
def create
    cliente = params.require(:referral).permit(:nomeAfiliado, :nomeReferenciado, :comissao, :validadeComissao)
    Referral.create cliente
  end
end
```

My `cadastroTeste.html.erb`

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="/afiliados">Voltar</a>
        <%= form_for Referral.new do |form| %>
            Nome <input type="text" name="referral[nomeAfiliado]"><br/>
            Nome Referenciado <input type="text" name="referral[nomeRef]"><br/>
            Comissão <input type="number" name="referral[comissao]"><br/>
            Válido até <input type="date" name="referral[validadeRef]"><br/>
            <button type="submit">Criar</button>
        <% end %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am following a tutorial from Alura (online programming school) and don't know what to do. I've tried changing my routes.rb to referral#create, but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the tutorial what it has but you are getting this error because of:

```
<%= form_for Referral.new do |form| %>
```

which expects a `ReferralController` and a route defined to its `create` action. You are trying to let Rails detect the controller and action automatically using its conventions on the form but you are not using the conventions on the controller. By this statement, I mean that the `Referral` object should be created on the `ReferralController` create action instead of `AfiliadosController`.

If you still want to make this work you could do:

```
<%= form_for afiliados_path do |form| %>
```

You could read more about this here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-model-objects

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much =)
And sorry for the noob question, started on Rails yesterday!